# Returning index of an array based on mixture of values(integer,string) or (integer,float)

Tags: javascript, arrays, percentage

Hi I am trying to find a index for a number in percentage and integer array. Say `arraynum = ['10%','250','20%','500']` and user sends a value `15%`,in which range does this number resides? I could find index for a integer number using this code

```
    function test(number, ranges) {
  for (var i = 0; i < ranges.length; ++i) {
    if (number < ranges[i]) {
      return i;
    }
  }
}


var ranges = [2000, 4000, 6000, 999999];

console.log(test(1710, ranges));
```

Now I have **mixture of integer and percentage value** inside a array and number that a user pass to this function can be a integer,decimal or percentage How to find in which index does the given number resides? Should I convert all value in the mixture array to some format? How to do this? Can someone please help me with this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why are you doing this `number < ranges[i]`? I thought you want to compare if it is that number that the user inputted.

Comment: I need to do two steps like compare a number with given array if not find in which range the number is in and get it index. @RaxWeber

Comment: any boundaries for ranges?(upperLimit,lowerLimit)

Comment: yes,999999 @Aravind

Comment: my question is that only is there any fixed range **Don't tell** (0,99999) but some meaningful range based on your functionality?

Comment: sorry 100% is the limit for percentage and in integer i cant fix a limit its a bit big processing. It can be any integer value so that I fix it to 99999. @Aravind

Comment: in your code **arraynum = ['10%','250','20%','500']** and **ranges = [2000, 4000, 6000, 999999]** why two different arrays?

Comment: ranges array is working. I need to work with mixture of integer and percentage that is arraynum. Am I not clear? @Aravind

Comment: start a discussion chat please!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Checking condition for mixture of values with one single input is little tricky and you need to go for **JSON array**. 
Please run

```js
var array_of_elements = [{

  "Price": 250,
  "Percentage": "10"
}, {
  "Price": 500,
  "Percentage": "25"
}, {
  "Price": 750,
  "Percentage": "50"
}, {
  "Price": 1000,
  "Percentage": "75"
}];

function test(number_or_percent, array) {

  for (var i = 0; i < array.length; ++i) {
    if (number_or_percent.charAt(number_or_percent.length - 1) == "%") {

      if (parseInt(array[i].Percentage) > parseInt(number_or_percent.slice(0, ((number_or_percent.length) - 1)))) {
        return i;
      }
    } else {
      if (array[i].Price > parseInt(number_or_percent)) {

        return i;
      }
    }
  }
}
console.log(test('100', array_of_elements));
console.log(test('30%', array_of_elements));
```

**Is this what you want?**

Answer (score 1):

Use [`parseFloat()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseFloat) to get the floating-point value of a string. You can use the fact that it only parses up until the first non-numeric character in the string in order to ignore the `%`.

Here is an implementation using [`Array#findIndex`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/findIndex) from ES6.

```
function test(number, ranges) {
    var num = parseFloat(number);
    return ranges.findIndex(function(element) {
        return num === parseFloat(element);
    });
}
```

Comment: I would be careful with findIndex if you aren't using a polyfill as it isn't support very well in browsers yet. Perhaps it might be better to use the [odash version: https://lodash.com/docs/4.16.4#findIndex

Comment: @thesublimeobject Right, the bulk of my answer is just `parseFloat`. They can do whatever they want for finding the index. Their loop would be fine even.

Comment: oh for sure. No issue with the answer whatsoever. Just wanted to point that out incase they didn't realize.

Comment: Thank you.I tried with this and getting -1 as index here is a fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/anusibi/Lvsvw6mn/5/  @4castle

Comment: @Anu Is the data sorted? It's unclear to me what your input and output is meant to represent.

Comment: Sorry my data is not sorted. Its given in random, Should I format my array? How should I. Can you please help me? @4castle

Comment: I am bit confused with mixture of integer and percentage value. How to sort them? :( @4castle

Answer (score 1):

You might restructure your code like so

```
arraynum = ['10%','250','20%','500'];
function test(value, arr) {
  return arr.indexOf(value.toString());
}

test("10%", arraynum); // 0
test("500", arraynum); // 3
```

Comment: Does this gives me index for decimal,integer and percentage values? @Damilola

Comment: Yes, I believe it should give you the first matched index for either integer or percentage values. It should be agnostic of the original value type since the value has been converted to string.

Comment: I tried with this and I am getting -1. Can you please see my edits in my question. @Damilola

Comment: See my edited answer. You should get correct index for existing element and -1 if element is not found

Comment: Thats working. But @Damilola user can give any input like test('25%', arraynum) or test('200', arraynum) for this I am getting index -1. Am I not clear?

Comment: if user input `test('25%', arraynum)`, may I ask what you would like the function to return. This would help to understand your question better.

Comment: Think the arraynum has many value. like it should get range. should I change my array to same type like every value to percentage or every value to some common format to find the index where the number reside. this number [1,5] now I enter 3 then index should be 1 @Damilola

Comment: Can you explain the range concept better? It would help if I could know the expected response should user input something like `test('25%', arraynum)`

Comment: I need the index as response. For arraynum[100,200,300] if i give number 150 my return should be 1 @Damilola